# How can I get the selected rows of choice form the Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe **(named energy)** with list of countries and other information.  The image is shown below.

I want to select only specific countries and their relevant information. The countries I need are selected by another dataframe named **SCI_Mago**.

How can I do that in pandas?
I will write the pseudo code of what I want. I cannot help myself with the exact code and whatever I tried gave me errors.

## Pseudo Code

```
#First I create the list from a dataframe named SCI_Mago. I want these countries for my next data frame
country_list =SCI_Mago['Country'].tolist()

#I use this list to get only relevant countries from another dataframe named 'energy'
new_DF = energy[energy['Country'] ==  country_list]
```

...

[image: image of dataframe named 'energy']

Comment: how about isin : `energy[energy['Country'].isin(country_list)]` ?

Comment: Thanks, if you can post it as answer, I will accept it. It works